# Docker container fails to start

Tags: apache, docker, containers

I have this container: 5.6.21-apache from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

I have installed all I need and my application but I made a mistake doing something wrong with Apache configs.

When I try start my container I get this message:

> docker start -ai my-container
>
> [Mon May 02 19:46:33.358838 2016] [core:warn] [pid 1] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
>   [Mon May 02 19:46:33.365305 2016] [core:warn] [pid 1] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
>   AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/etc/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/' for main error log
>   AH00014: Configuration check failed

How can I solve this? I want drop this configs. I can't just lose this container.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile, if you didn't use a dockerfile, can you explain how you created your image. Also, can you post your config, so we can see what went wrong?

Comment: ken the problem is not with my Dockerfile because it was working, the problem is on my config changes! i make a mistake put a wrong  line config in apache.conf and after that the container is not starting any more.

Comment: Did you make the change directly in the container? If so, how did you make the change? I'll update my answer with another option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't given enough information to go on, I'm just going to guess. Feel free to add more info to your questions so that it will be easier to help you.

If you search your apache config file and look for `APACHE_LOG_DIR`, it will probably point to your issue.

This line in the logs is interesting:

> Cannot access directory '/etc/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/'

Not sure why you would have a log directory under /etc/apache2, but look in that directory to see what you have in there, and set `APACHE_LOG_DIR` accordingly.

Another thing you can try is to do the following

```
docker commit (container name or Id) myimage

docker run -it myimage /bin/bash
```

Then commit changes again to create the fixed image and try to start it up like normal.

```
docker commit (container Id or name) myimage2

docker run -d -p 80:80 myimage2
```

Basically save the current container state as an image so you can start it up in a shell and fix the issues. Then once you have fixed the issues you can create a new image and use that to run your container.

I usually avoid this pain by not making changes directly in the containers, I only make changes in my dockerfiles and then when I need to make, I change the dockerfile. If there is an issue, I just need to fix the dockerfile, and the containers don't get in this bad state.

Comment: thx ken but we dont have "-e" option on comand docker start.

i just need edit the apache2.conf localized in /etc/apache2/apache.conf but because i cant start the container i cant edit this file... there is another way to edit a container file without start?

Comment: Your right, I was thinking docker run. I guess that leaves the second option, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case after rebooting computer (or sleeping/restarting system) I have a problem with starting a container.
Before run start I use docker exec command.
Example:

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

(Have a message that container is not running and then)

```
docker start CONTAINER_NAME
```